# Tensorflow tf.data.Dataset takes too much time to generate dataset. Better way to optimize it?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have `.stem.mp4` files each of which is composed of multiple audio sources. 
Each length of file is 2 minutes to 6 minutes. It varies a lot.

When I try to make `tf.data.Dataset` out of it, it seems to take a lot of time to generate a `input_batch` much more than my model makes a prediction of a given batch.

Let me illustarte an example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

sample_data = tf.random.normal((5, 755200, 2)) # 5 sources of audio, stereo channel

# First axis is the mixture of the audio, so this is the input
# Rest 4 axes are the each source of the audio(eg. bass, drum, vocals, etc) so these are the output
input_mixture = sample_data[0, :, :]
target_mixtures = sample_data[1:, :, :]
target_mixtures = np.column_stack(target_mixtures)

length = 44100 * 11 # I want to split these into length of 11 seconds
strides = 44100 # 1 second stride

ds_inp = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_mixture))
ds_inp = ds_inp.window(length, shift=strides, drop_remainder=True)
ds_inp = ds_inp.flat_map(lambda windows: windows.batch(length))
ds_inp = ds_inp.map(lambda windows: windows, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

ds_tar = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((target_mixtures))
ds_tar = ds_tar.window(length, shift=strides, drop_remainder=True)
ds_tar = ds_tar.flat_map(lambda windows: windows.batch(length))
ds_tar = ds_tar.map(lambda windows: windows, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

ds_total = [ds_inp, ds_tar]
total_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(ds_total))
total_ds = total_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
total_ds = total_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

This is how I made a `tf.data.Dataset` from the given file.

And when I measure the time how fast does this make a `input_batch` and `output_batch`,

```
%%time
for i, j in total_ds.take(1):
    pass
# Wall time: 18.3 s
```

My model has about 100 million variables, but since it fairly has a simple structure so that it takes about 6 seconds to generate a predicted_batch out of given input_batch.

So my problem is, is there any way to make it to generate `input_batch`, `output_batch` faster?
(My assumption is that, as this 'window' the given arrays, there is no better way to improve this.)

Obviously all of the files are big enough not to be cached.